# Install4j takes time to cleanup itself

Tags: install4j

I have an issue in uninstallation. After uninstallation ,to exit the UI , when the user clicks on "close" button ,it takes time (around 8-9s) to cleanup itself.I have used only "context.finish(0)" script on the click event.

After some analysis i understood that even after deleting all the files during uninstallation some folder like ".install4j" and "jre" are remaining and they are deleted after clicking the close button.Maybe because they are used by installer UI itself. Thats why it takes time to close UI. During this time the UI is unresponsive (hanged state). Any solution or workaround to avoid this as the UI is unresponsive and we want to avoid that.

Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to disable the cleanup.

Comment: I understand . But anyway to reduce the time required to do it. any workaround?

Comment: No, sorry, there is no such flag.